# Padding that does not affect one child

Tags: html, css

I'm making a responsive web design. But my CSS knowledge could have been better. I want a padding on a div, but I don't want it to affect the title.

See this example:
[image]

I want the title to be were it is, but the little squares to have a margin at the left side.

I've tried to set a padding and then reset the title position with relative positioning. But I don't like that solution because the title is pushing the squares more than necessary.

I've also tried to set a div where the cross is, but I can't manage to get it under the title and on the left side of all squares since the title is floated left and the squares right.

[**Here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F7ssh/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="siteContainer">
    <div id="titleContainer">
        <h1 id="title">This is the long title</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    // more...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#siteContainer {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}
#title {
    display: inline-block;
}
#titleContainer {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #DDCCAA;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: This is really unclear.

Comment: How is it unclear? I want the exact result as if you add a padding on left side (say 100px), BUT I want the title to be as it is right now in the example.

Comment: The padding solution is a good solution.

Comment: But it doesn't work as I would like it to work because it affect the title as well. And that's the whole problem.

Comment: You tried padding-left on the container and then relative position on the title. What about padding-left on the container (100px) and then a negative text-indent on the title (-100px)?

Comment: Adding space on the left is a good solution. You add margin of 100px and move text by 110px to the left with negative margin: http://jsfiddle.net/gBmcb/.

Comment: That text-indent worked perfectly, never seen that before. Thanks!

Comment: And that negative margin worked also fine, think I will go with that because I understand what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you want the padding on the left of the container to be (100px), you can set as a negative `text-indent` value on the title (-100px).

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about the box model? Do some research on CSS box model and you will see where your problem is.

Let me give you an example:

If you have a div with the width of 100px and add a padding of 10px, the width of your div will be 120px, both sides will take 10px from the padding, you can solve this in two ways, one is to make the div width smaller "80px" and the second is to use box-sizing: border-box;

Hope this helped.